# Filter an array in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: arrays, filter, azure-logic-apps

This seems like it should be straightforward but the fact it isn't suggests I haven't understood something.
I have a simple array variable with content as below. I want to filter it so I only see items where policy is X so that I can get the value for the document element.

I've tried:

- `filter @variables('myArray') where @equals('policy','X')`
- `@contains('policy','X')`
- `filter @variables('myArray') where @contains(@variables('myArray'),'X'`

In each case the array enters the filter array action whole and leaves it completely empty. Any assistance gratefully received.

```json
[

  {
    "document": "A",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "X"
  },

  {
    "document": "B",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Y"
  },

  {
    "document": "C",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Z"
  }

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Parse JSON` before Filtering the array. Considering the sample which you have provided we have tested it in our Logic App and this is working. Here is the screenshot of my Logic App for your Reference:

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Considering Another Sample of Array

```
[
  {
    "document": "A",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "X"
  },
  {
    "document": "B",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Y"
  },
  {
    "document": "C",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Z"
  },
{
    "document": "D",
    "min": 7500002,
    "policy": "X"
  }
]
```

RESULT:

[image]

Below is the code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Filter_array_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                    "where": "@equals(item()['policy'], 'X')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Query"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "SampleArray1",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "document": "A",
                                    "min": 7500001,
                                    "policy": "X"
                                },
                                {
                                    "document": "B",
                                    "min": 7500001,
                                    "policy": "Y"
                                },
                                {
                                    "document": "C",
                                    "min": 7500001,
                                    "policy": "Z"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('SampleArray1')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "document": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "min": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "policy": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "document",
                                "min",
                                "policy"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Succinct and successful.